# Twilio API - How to Opt-Out a phone number

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api

When a new user signs up, we're going to give them a checkbox where they can Opt-**IN** or Opt-**OUT** of receiving SMS messages.

I can easily track this on my own by making sure our application doesn't send texts their way, but I'm wondering if it makes more sense for me to just add them as **opted out** on Twilio?

I'm still playing around with this idea, but regardless I'm not seeing any API endpoints (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api) for **Opt-In** or **Opt-Out**.

**Questions:**

- How would I Opt-Out a phone number if I choose to go that route?
- Is it better to manage this list on my end, or to use Twilio for this (if it's possible), or to be redundant and manage my own list in addition to Twilio enforcing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no API for developers to opt users' phone numbers in or out of messages so **you should maintain that opt out list yourself** within your own application as you described at the start of your question.

[Twilio does make it possible for users to completely opt out of messages from a number (or messaging service) using the industry standard opt out words (STOP, STOPALL, UNSUBSCRIBE, CANCEL, END, and QUIT)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-). When a user sends one of those words on their own to your number then Twilio will cease sending messages to that person. You will receive the message as a webhook so you can watch for those keywords and update your application's opt out list too.

I recommend that if you want users to opt out of messages that you get them to do so as part of your system rather via the STOP mechanic. That way, to re-enable messages they can do so through your system and not have to send an opt in message (START, YES and UNSTOP) to open up to messages again.

Comment: This is unfortunate, as this makes it complicated for a user to opt back in via text if they don't have the phone number(s) on hand. @philnash could you cite where in the API this webhook lives? That's a really good idea for me to update my own list if they Opt-Out via SMS.

Comment: It's the regular messaging webhook. You can tell it's an opt out message because it contains one of (and only one of) the opt out words from my answer above. I agree it is complicated for a user to opt back in if they opted out by texting STOP or similar, which is why I recommend you direct your users to your application for that sort of control as best you can.

Comment: So you can use some custom words like MYAPPSTOP to keep a similar functionality while skipping the Twilio "blacklist".

Comment: You could encourage your own users to use a different key word to cancel messages if you want to be able to control the messages and your blacklist. You would have to put the code in place that records that and ensures you don't send to those opted out users though.

Comment: Is there a way to get a count or a list of numbers that have opted out from receiving text messages?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware of Patrick. Like I said, you will get the webhook with the STOP message or you will get an error from the API if you try to send to a number that is opted out, so you should maintain your own list.

Comment: @philnash - Is there a way to see the opt out list in the twilio developer console? This would sure help us troubleshoot SMS issues.

Comment: @ScubaSteve There is not, what sort of issues are you having?

Comment: @philnash - We get the odd report of employees not receiving text messages that have been marked as 'Received'. It'd be good to know if there have been cases where our employees used the standard opt-out replies. 

Currently we're not handling this scenario in our software.

Comment: @ScubaSteve if the employee has opted out via "STOP" then you will get an error when you try to send the SMS via the API. If the message was sent by Twilio then they have not opted out.

Comment: @philnash I would love to say I agree with your answer but I am currently a paid subscriber of a service built upon Twilio. If I add my own cell number to their platform. I see something I didn’t think was possible. As expected I can text the Start/Stop keywords and get the expected Twilio responses. I can; however, use their system to opt my number back and I don’t get the Twilio reply. It seems I can opt in and opt out from their system without getting replies on my phone. Are they deleting the replies on the fly and sending Start/Stop messages on my behalf?

Comment: @G-J it is possible that they have opted to control opt-outs themselves, rather than using the default behaviour.